time check to open a position does not work as expected in backTest (Strategy tester)
i have an expert advisor that opens positions each day at 1:10am only. it works perfectly on chart on forward test but when i try to back test it using strategy tester, i see that it opens positions on 1:10 but also on some other random times as well! does any one know what could be the problem?
here is the code that checks the time:
datetime tradeTime=D'01:10:00';
datetime currentTime = TimeCurrent(); 
void OnTick(){
        if (TimeHour(currentTime) == TimeHour(tradeTime))
            {
                if(TimeMinute(currentTime) == TimeMinute(tradeTime)){
                //strategy
            }
        }
}



Your code is correct, all the pending trades (Buy Limit & Sell Limit) are being opened at 01:10 AM everyday. The Market Buy and Market Sell trades are opening on other times, they are converted trades from Pending Trades. A Pending trade can be converted into market trade whenever price hits that price level.
Kindly execute the same script and execute a Market Buy order, and you will see its only opening at 01:10 AM

In strategy tester it's best to refer to time of a bar instead of TimeCurrent().
I don't recall precisely how that's been done in MQL4; in MQL5 it is iTime(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,shift) where shift is the referring integer to the relevant bar.

You might already know, this idea is wrong for all cases, the Strategy runs in S/T on TimeFrames like M15, M30, H1, H4 et al

Thnx, I did not know this idea is wrong. I'll test it on a recent EA of mine, which is using those bar times intensively.

No need to test - iTime(...) always reports candle time, so you will never see a time "between" or "during" the Candle evolution, only its administratively set beginning, not a moment 10 minutes later or likewise for other TimeFrames ...
